# Stay on bootstrap modal screen after button action submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap modal and inside I have a form. I want that the modal stays open after form submit but it closes. I have checked adding a popover to the button ( which didn't work ) to force to show a message before the modal closes.

Is there any way to make it stay open? I want to show the user a confirmation after submit. Couldn't find any answer in older posts.

Maybe I have to render different the template in the view after submit ?
This is the button definition inside FORM POST:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
```

I have also tried adding : onclick="$('#{{p.id}}').modal({'backdrop': 'static'});"

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: I would use jquery submit() with ajax something like giving an id to form(my-form) and than jQuery('#my-form').submit( function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //ajax submit});

Comment: I have addeed that at the end of my html but doesn't work.

Comment: show me your script. The markup and the js

Comment: look at here http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/WBnRV/13/

Comment: Now I have it working as the fiddle but, it doesn't submit the form.. I am not getting the POST event to process the form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So extended to send ajax request

**The Markup**

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-custom" data-toggle="modal">Open Form</a>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">My Form</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="my-form">
                <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </form>

        </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
        </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
        </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal -->
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('submit','#my-form',function(event){    
    event.preventDefault()
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "", // some php
        data: formData,
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {}
   });
});
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/WBnRV/17/